# Spring aop Pointcut is not well-formed

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut expression="exection(* info.fdlife.service.UserService.*(..))"
        id="aopProductUserService" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="aopProductUserService" />
</aop:config>
```

Here is some of `applicationContext.xml` (Spring Framework), `info.fdlife.service.UserService` is a interface. I get some error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 11
>   exection(* info.fdlife.service.UserService.*(..))

What does this mean?

Comment: You have a _typo_ in `exection`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ee......it is say my class name was mistake? I checked,it's right.

Comment: What? No, it's `execution`, not `exection`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks a lot, I never remind it. 
I did not expect was so low-level error.